# boost scoped_ptr with char* type throws initialisation error

Tags: c++, boost

**summary:** to use boost::scoped_ptr  with char* data type. I have written my own Str class and function based on Accelerated C++ chap12. Everything works good but just for my curiosity purpose I tried to use boost::scoped_ptr but After spending hours I made no success.

To be noted: If I dont use boost ptr everything works as expected.

**Issue::error:**  no matching constructor for initialization of 'boost::scoped_ptr'
    boost::scoped_ptr< char* > buffer_smrt_ptr( buffer );
                               ^                ~~~~~~

Below are my code

```
// test of copy function
    Str test_cpy( "String copy test");
    char* buffer = new char[ test_cpy.size() ];
    boost::scoped_ptr< char* > buffer_smrt_ptr( buffer );
    Str::size_type n_len  = test_cpy.copy( buffer_smrt_ptr,10, 0);
    buffer_smrt_ptr[  n_len ] = '\0';
    printf( "your  copied string: == %s\n", buffer );
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The error you encounter results from the following *declaration-initialization* mismatch:

```
boost::scoped_ptr< char* > buffer_smrt_ptr( buffer );
//                     ^
```

That is, when declaring the `<T>` type of `boost::scoped_ptr<T>`, it is not the *type of a pointer to the stored value*, but the *type of the pointed value* itself. Hence, the asterisk is redundant and should be removed.

However, for storing pointers to dynamically allocated arrays and accessing their value through `operator[]` one should use [`boost::scoped_array<T>`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/smart_ptr/scoped_array.htm) instead:

```
Str test_cpy( "String copy test" );
char* buffer = new char[ test_cpy.size() ];
boost::scoped_array< char > buffer_smrt_ptr( buffer );
//            ^^^^^  ^^^^
```

Additionally, `boost::scoped_ptr<T>` (as well as `boost::scoped_array<T>`) is a non-copyable type, if you aim to pass it to the `Str::copy()` member function either catch it by reference **OR** get a raw pointer:

```
Str::size_type n_len = test_cpy.copy(buffer_smrt_ptr.get(), 10, 0);
//                                                  ^^^^^^
```

Going further, if your `test_cpy.size()` member function returns a string length without a trailing `\0`, you probably need to increase the buffer by one more character:

```
char* buffer = new char[ test_cpy.size() + 1 ];
//                                       ^^^
```

Comment: @PiotS. Thanks a ton  mate for explaining so clearly and in detail.

Answer (score 2):

You should use `boost::scoped_array` instead of `boost::scoped_ptr`. It is smart pointer for managing array. Also its template type should be `char` instead of `char*`. I think your compiler error is because of second issue.